# helm list : cannot list configmaps in the namespace "kube-system"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have installed helm 2.6.2 on the kubernetes 8 cluster. `helm init` worked fine. but when I run `helm list` it giving this error.

```
 helm list
Error: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list configmaps in the namespace "kube-system"
```

How to fix this RABC error message?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Once these commands:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'      
helm init --service-account tiller --upgrade
```

were run, the issue has been solved.

Comment: Note that this assigns `--clusterrole=cluster-admin`, which will certainly fix permissions problems, but might not be the fix you want. It's better to create your own service accounts, (cluster)roles, and (cluster)rolebindings with the exact permissions you need.

Comment: `The accepted answer gives full admin access to Helm which is not the best solution security wise` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53277281/2777965).

Comment: when run "init", must have "--upgrade", other questions don't mention it.

Comment: When I run  `kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'` I get `Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "tiller-deploy" not found`

Answer (score 37):

## More Secure Answer

The accepted answer gives full admin access to Helm which is not the best solution security wise. With a little more work, we can restrict Helm's access to a particular namespace. More details in the [Helm documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#role-based-access-control).

```
$ kubectl create namespace tiller-world
namespace "tiller-world" created
$ kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace tiller-world
serviceaccount "tiller" created
```

Define a Role that allows Tiller to manage all resources in `tiller-world` like in `role-tiller.yaml`:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-manager
  namespace: tiller-world
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "batch", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

Then run:

```
$ kubectl create -f role-tiller.yaml
role "tiller-manager" created
```

In `rolebinding-tiller.yaml`,

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-binding
  namespace: tiller-world
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: tiller
  namespace: tiller-world
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: tiller-manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Then run:

```
$ kubectl create -f rolebinding-tiller.yaml
rolebinding "tiller-binding" created
```

Afterwards you can run `helm init` to install Tiller in the `tiller-world` namespace.

```
$ helm init --service-account tiller --tiller-namespace tiller-world
```

Now prefix all commands with `--tiller-namespace tiller-world` or set `TILLER_NAMESPACE=tiller-world` in your environment variables.

## More Future Proof Answer

Stop using Tiller. Helm 3 removes the need for Tiller completely. If you are using Helm 2, you can use `helm template` to generate the yaml from your Helm chart and then run `kubectl apply` to apply the objects to your Kubernetes cluster.

```
helm template --name foo --namespace bar --output-dir ./output ./chart-template
kubectl apply --namespace bar --recursive --filename ./output -o yaml
```

Comment: Note, once you do this you will need to prefix all helm commands with `--tiller-namespace tiller-world` or set `TILLER_NAMESPACE=tiller-world` in your environment variables.

Comment: Totally agree with the future proof answer. The helm folks seem to realise that the RBAC stuff made things too complex to manage. They are only at alpha, but worth a look: [Helm 3, alpha 1](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.0.0-alpha.1)

Comment: Agreed, RBAC is a bit much to get your hands on at first. I'm still struggling with it but making progress.

Comment: Is the Persistent Volumes creation the accept practice by helm? Should we create also another cluster-role and binding for this case?

Answer (score 20):

Helm runs with "default" service account. You should provide permissions to it.

**For read-only permissions:**

```
kubectl create rolebinding default-view --clusterrole=view --serviceaccount=kube-system:default --namespace=kube-system
```

**For admin access: Eg: to install packages.**

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:default
```

Comment: After running `kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:default`, and then run `helm list` I still get `Error: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:tiller:default" cannot list configmaps in the namespace "tiller": no RBAC policy matched`

Answer (score 4):

The default serviceaccount does not have API permissions. Helm likely needs to be assigned a service account, and that service account given API permissions. See the RBAC documentation for granting permissions to service accounts: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#service-account-permissions

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tiller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tiller
    namespace: kube-system
```

`kubectl apply -f your-config-file-name.yaml`

and then update helm instalation to use serviceAccount:

`helm init --service-account tiller --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I got a this error while trying to install tiller in offline mode, I thought the 'tiller' service account didn't have enough rights but at it turns out that a network policy was blocking the communication between tiller and the api-server.

The solution was to create a network policy for tiller allowing all egress communication of tiller

Answer (score 0):

`export TILLER_NAMESPACE=<your-tiller-namespace>` solved it for me, if `<your-tiller-namespace>` is not `kube-system`. This points the Helm client to the right Tiller namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an EKS cluster from AWS and are facing the forbidden issue ( *eg*: `forbidden: User ... cannot list resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "default"` then this worked for me:

Solution:

1. Ensure you have configured AWS
2. Ensure that configured user has the permission to access the cluster.