# How do I give myself permission to create clusterrolebindings on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rbac, google-kubernetes-engine

My command `helm list` is failing with the message:

```
Error: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list configmaps in the namespace "kube-system"
```

And I found some results that tell me how to set up RBAC roles and rolebindings, like for example:

[helm list : cannot list configmaps in the namespace "kube-system"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672523/helm-list-cannot-list-configmaps-in-the-namespace-kube-system)

and

https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/

but these fail for me as well with this error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "tiller-clusterrolebinding.yaml": clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "$USER" cannot create clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io at the cluster scope: Required "container.clusterRoleBindings.create" permission.
```

Now after some searching I found this answer:

[Cannot create clusterrolebinding on fresh GKE cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770624/cannot-create-clusterrolebinding-on-fresh-gke-cluster)

Which gives this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) User [$USER] does not have permission to access project [$PROJECT:setIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
```

This last error finally seems to give me a good tip, I seem to not be an administrator/owner of this project, so I'm asking the owner of the project if he can give me those permissions. He's non-technical, so he'll have to do it through the GUI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would need one of the following roles to create clusterrolebindings in k8s:

- Owner
- Kubernetes Engine Admin
- Composer Worker

You can check permissions and roles in Roles tab in GCP

[image: roles]

And you can assign one of these roles (or create a custom role) in IAM & Admin Tab

[image]

You need one of the following roles with **resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy** permission to set IAM policy roles for somebody else (which I believe your admin does)

- Organization Administrator
- Owner
- Project IAM Admin

[image]

Your project owner, organization administrator, or somebody with project IAM admin role will need to give your **$USER** one of the following roles, or create a custom role: Owner (less likely), Kubernetes Engine Admin (most likely, not following the security principle of **least privilege** though) or Composer Worker. Then your **$USER** will be able to create `clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io at the cluster scope`

Comment: For anyone wondering: above changes might need quite a few mins to take effect.