# Installing dask on gke with clusterIP scheduler and port forwarding - tcp connection times out when creating a dask.distibuted client in python

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, dask, kubernetes-helm, portforwarding

I tried to deploy dask on gke cluster using helm and tiller.
I do not have permissions to create external IPs for my cluster, so I set up the dask scheduler as a clusterIP instead of loadbalancer. I then used kubectl provided port forwarding to forward the dask scehduler service to my local machine.

I have a python code (a simple dask example) where I want to connect the distributed client to the (forwarded) tcp port of the dask scheduler and launch computes in my gke cluster.
However I receive a timeout on the tcp connection.

I am wondering where I could have gone wrong in this process or if I need more enable more permissions in my gcp account to get this to work. Any pointers you can provide is greatly appreciated.
Please note that I was able to open the jupyter notebook on the forwarded http port and able to trigger some computations on the default 3 workers that dask created on my gke

I am pasting below the the python code I ran, the error I see, the current status of pods, nodes, services setup for dask on gke and the commands I used to setup dask on my gcp-gke

my sample python program (dask-example.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.array as da

client = Client('tcp://127.0.0.1:8080')

array = da.ones((1000, 1000, 1000))

mn = array.mean().compute()  # Should print 1.0

print(mn)
```

Error message (on running python3 dask-example.py):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/userenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 286, in connect
    comm = await asyncio.wait_for(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 498, in wait_for
    raise exceptions.TimeoutError()
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trial.py", line 17, in <module>
    client = Client('tcp://127.0.0.1:8080', timeout=10)
  File "/home/userenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 743, in __init__
    self.start(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/userenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 948, in start
    sync(self.loop, self._start, **kwargs)
  File "/home/userenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 340, in sync
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/userenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 324, in f
    result[0] = yield future
  File "/home/userenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/userenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1038, in _start
    await self._ensure_connected(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/userenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1095, in _ensure_connected
    comm = await connect(
  File "/home/userenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 308, in connect
    raise IOError(
OSError: Timed out trying to connect to tcp://127.0.0.1:8080 after 10 s
```

status of dask on my gke

kubectl get po #shows this

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
my-dask-jupyter-565c5c5659-w4s76           1/1     Running             0          27h
my-dask-scheduler-6bf8bc8bbf-xgj2q         1/1     Running             0          27h
my-dask-worker-68b5b695bd-l2b6m            1/1     Running             0          27h
my-dask-worker-68b5b695bd-xnssz            1/1     Running             0          27h
my-dask-worker-68b5b695bd-z68wt            1/1     Running             0          27h
```

kubectl get no #shows this

```
NAME                                          STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
gke-dask-cluster-default-pool-d3f451b1-gp47   Ready    <none>   27h   v1.17.14-gke.1200
gke-dask-cluster-default-pool-d3f451b1-rk8z   Ready    <none>   27h   v1.17.14-gke.1200
```

kubectl get svc #shows this

```
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
kubernetes          ClusterIP   10.83.240.1    <none>        443/TCP           27h
my-dask-jupyter     ClusterIP   10.83.244.84   <none>        80/TCP            27h
my-dask-scheduler   ClusterIP   10.83.244.59   <none>        8786/TCP,80/TCP   27h
```

Commands I used to setup dask (thanks to this post https://libinruan.github.io/2019/05/24/Set-up-Kubernetes-clusters-for-Python-ML/)

```
export PROJECTID='mygcp'
export EMAIL="user4098765@gmail.com"
export ZONE='us-central1-c'
export REGION='us-central1' 
export MIN_WORKER_NODES=0
export MAX_WORKER_NODES=100
export CLUSTER_NAME='dask-cluster'
export WORKER_MACHINE_TYPE='n1-standard-2'
export MACHINE_TYPE='n1-standard-2'
NUM_NODES=2
 
gcloud config set project $PROJECTID

gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com

gcloud container clusters create $CLUSTER_NAME --machine-type $MACHINE_TYPE --num-nodes $NUM_NODES --zone $ZONE --cluster-version latest

gcloud container clusters get-credentials $DASK_KUBE_CLUSTER_NAME --zone=$DASK_KUBE_CLUSTER_ZONE --project $DASK_GCLOUD_PROJECT

kubectl config set-cluster $DASK_KUBE_CLUSTER_NAME

kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=$EMAIL

kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace=kube-system

kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
helm init --service-account tiller --wait

kubectl --namespace=kube-system patch deployment tiller-deploy --type=json \
--patch='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/command", "value": ["/tiller", "--listen=localhost:44134"]}]'

gcloud container clusters get-credentials $CLUSTER_NAME --zone=$ZONE --project $PROJECTID

kubectl config set-cluster $DASK_KUBE_CLUSTER_NAME

helm install -n my-dask stable/dask -f dask-worker-spec.yml --set scheduler.serviceType=ClusterIP --set jupyter.serviceType=ClusterIP
```

Comment: Hello, I've used the setup like you've posted and stumbled upon the same issue. I reckon that this guide is kinda old and the Helm chart is already deprecated. Have you considered using newer Helm chart and Helm3? I've used this [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/kubernetes-helm.html) with [Helm3](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/) and I was able to connect (it told me about the mismatches in module version but it connected). Unfortunately my Python/Dask knowledge ends there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to reproduce the same behavior as described in the question.

I encourage you to check the newer version of `dask` which is available on it's homepage as the one used in the question is **deprecated**.

**TL;DR**

**Use the same Python modules (`dask`, `distributed`, etc..) versions of the software that `dask-scheduler` is using!**

---

#### Reproduction of the setup used in the question

- Create `GKE` cluster:

  - `$ gcloud beta container clusters create "gke-dask" --zone "europe-west3-c" --no-enable-basic-auth --cluster-version "1.17.13-gke.2600" --release-channel "regular" --machine-type "e2-standard-4"`

> `e2-standard-4` = 4 cores and 16GB RAM machine

- Connect to cluster:

  - `$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials gke-dask --zone=europe-west3-c`
- Install `Helm` **v2** (if needed: *[Stackoverflow.com: Permission issues with Helm v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672523/helm-list-cannot-list-configmaps-in-the-namespace-kube-system)*):

  - *[Helm.sh: Docs: Intro: Install](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/)*
  - `$ helm init`
- Run the Helm Chart:

  - `$ helm install -n my-dask stable/dask  --set scheduler.serviceType=ClusterIP --set jupyter.serviceType=ClusterIP`

To identify the issue I ran some tests:

- `$ kubectl port-forward` `dask-scheduler` to my machine and use the example Python code that was in the question. I installed the dependencies this code needed but in different versions (`$ pip install dask[complete]`. **Code failed with the same message as in the question**.
- `$ kubectl run -it --rm ubuntu -- /bin/bash` - the error from the question indicated that it could be a network related problem. I used `ubuntu` `Pod` with the same Python installation to eliminate potential network connectivity issues (`port-forward`). **Code failed with the same message as in the question**.
- `$ kubectl exec -it DASK-SCHEDULER-POD-NAME -- /bin/bash` - if this is a network connectivity issue it should run on a `Pod` that is supposed to handle this code.  **Code ran successfully and returned `1.0`**.

I tried to use an `ubuntu` `Pod` with Python and it's modules more close with a version to the one in a `dask-scheduler`. **It produced an error different from the one in a question**. This indicates that there is no inherent issue with the networking but with the software used (it's versions). I couldn't exactly replicate the setup used in `dask-scheduler` so I've used the image that `dask-scheduler` is using and spawned additional `Pod` to check if it will work through the `GKE` network. **It worked!**

> Please conisder below example to be a workaround!

Steps to run from your machine:

- `$ kubectl port-forward service/my-dask-scheduler --address 0.0.0.0 8786:8786 &` - forward `dask` service to your machine
- `$ docker run --rm -ti daskdev/dask:1.1.5 /bin/bash` - run a Docker container on your machine and `exec` into it's `bash`. This image is the same as your `dask-scheduler`'s to preserve Python and it's modules versions.
- Use folowing Python code inside of a container:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from dask.distributed 
import Client
import dask.array as da
client = Client('tcp://IP_ADDRESS:8786')
array = da.ones((1000, 1000, 1000))
mn = array.mean().compute() # Should print 1.0
print(mn)
```

> Please put in the "IP_ADDRESS" the IP address of your machine that is accessible from your Docker container!

You should get the following output:

```sh
(base) root@81fb5004ea4c:/# python3 script.py 
1.0
```

---

You could check Python [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for virtual environments.

Additional reference:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Access application cluster: Port forward access application cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into the issue. Can you please let me know how I can get the IP_ADDRESS of the machine accessible from inside the docker?

Comment: Update: I was able to get things working without needing a docker by using a virtualenv with dask == 2.30.0 and distributed==2.30.0. I also had to use helm install -n my-dask dask/dask... instead of helm install -n my-dask stable/dask. Also, thanks for the 'beta' in gcloud beta. This helped me move to dask versions >=2 . without the beta, I was stuck with dask==1.1.5 which I think needs the docker workaround mentioned in your solution

Comment: @dasknovice `gcloud beta` shouldn't make any differences in that regard. Please take a look on more information about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/components#alpha_and_beta_components). I'm not exactly sure what you mean by IP address of a machine accessible from inside the docker but I reckon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host) could help.